# Progressive Daedalian Opus

Tags: mathematics, optimization, tiling, polyomino

The 1990 Game Boy game [Daedalian Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daedalian_Opus) is essentially a series of 36 pentomino puzzles. In the first level, however, you only have three pentominos; the rest are introduced in the levels after that, one at a time. A good proportion of the shapes you have to fit the pentominos into are also plain rectangles. (See a tool-assisted speedrun of the game [here](https://tasvideos.org/4493M)).

That led me to the following problem. What is the smallest $k$ such that there is an ordering of the 12 distinct free pentominos where

- the first $k$ can tile a $5×k$ rectangle exactly
- the first $k+1$ can tile a $5×(k+1)$ rectangle exactly
- and so on, to the first $12$ tiling a $5×12$ rectangle exactly (which can always be done)?

For example, if $k=9$ there would have to exist an ordering – say `PINWVZXFTUYL` – where

- `PINWVZXFTUY` tiles a $5×11$ rectangle
- `PINWVZXFTU` tiles a $5×10$ rectangle
- `PINWVZXFT` tiles a $5×9$ rectangle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to tile a 2x5 rectangle with two distinct pentominos. But there are many ways to make such a sequence starting with three pentominos.

Here's an example, chosen for the unique tilings up to level 7:

> FPU-LXTVINWYZ
>  [image]

Here's a better example, with pic. I automated the bit I was doing manually (finding sets with one extra piece from the list of all possible pieces). The maximum is 8 pieces with unique tilings. 9 through 12 I just printed the first tiling.

> LTY-PWZVXFINU
>  [image]

While we're at it, the one sided pentomino case works too. There are six extra asymmetric pentominos (call them F', L', N', P', Y' and Z') for a total of 18. This time you can get all the way to a 5x12 with unique tilings.

> PP'V-YNFZN'F'Z'XLIUTWL'Y'
>  [image]